# SwiperJS slider option loop: true not working properly make slider disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Hi I'm having problem with my SwiperJS slider I use videos and iframeAPI to write videos into html, but when I want my slides to have a loop option video disappear, can someone help me with this here is example code, so basically in code now I have loop true option and slide videos don't show up at all but when you remove it everything working fine. Why is that happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Video</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- START SWIPERJS SLIDER -->
<style>
    .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide,
    .pd-swiperjs-video-iframe {
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 600px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-button-prev,
    .swiper-button-next {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .swiper-button-next:after, .swiper-button-prev:after {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #000;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div id="player1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div id="player2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div id="player3"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END SWIPERJS SLIDER -->

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      initialSlide: 1,
      effect: "coverflow",
      grabCursor: true,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: "auto",
      loop: true,
      coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 50,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
      },
    });

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var yt = [];
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        let w = '100%';
        let h = '100%';

        yt['player1'] = new YT.Player('player1', {
            width: w,
            height: h,
            videoId: '37cZyFIKHRQ',
        });
        yt['player2'] = new YT.Player('player2', {
            width: w,
            height: h,
            videoId: 'o3YIpredyNA',
            // Put this in order to start the video - We put this in second slider because we initialize the slider with second slide active
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            },
        });
        yt['player3'] = new YT.Player('player3', {
            width: w,
            height: h,
            videoId: 'Fx-zmUwV1pc',
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    swiper.on('transitionStart', function(){
        yt['player1'].pauseVideo();
        yt['player2'].pauseVideo();
        yt['player3'].pauseVideo();
    });

    swiper.on('transitionEnd', function(){
        var index = this.realIndex;
        var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide')[index];
        var slideVideo = slide.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        var slideVideoId = slideVideo.getAttribute('id');

        if(slideVideo != null || slideVideo != undefined){
            yt[slideVideoId].mute();
            yt[slideVideoId].playVideo();
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Why is that happening?"_ - probably due to the fact that Swiper creates "clones" of slides, when you have it in loop mode. For example the duplicate player IDs will likely become problematic then.

Comment: Can I somehow make infinite loop in code without need for loop true?

Comment: The way these slider libraries usually work, is that all the slides are put next to each other in one "line" - and then x-position of that line element gets manipulated, so that you only see a certain part of it in your slider viewport. And that's why they required cloned slides for endless looping. I can't tell you how much manipulation of what the library normally does, it would need to achieve your desired result without the clones.

Comment: Do you have any solution how can I fix this?

Comment: No, not as a quick-fix. I think you'll either need to find yourself a different slider library that supports what you want to achieve directly; or go look into how swiper works in a bit more detail. It _might_ be possible to use the events and methods it provides, to dynamically move elements to the "other side" (changing their position in the DOM), when the end on either side is reached ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created custom solution for problem

```js
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      initialSlide: 1,
      effect: "coverflow",
      grabCursor: true,
      allowTouchMove: true,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: "auto",
      loopedSlides: 3,
      coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 50,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      loop: false,
    });

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var yt = [];
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        let w = '100%';
        let h = '100%';

        yt['player1'] = new YT.Player('player1', {
            width: w,
            height: h,
            videoId: '37cZyFIKHRQ',
        });
        yt['player2'] = new YT.Player('player2', {
            width: w,
            height: h,
            videoId: 'o3YIpredyNA',
            // Put this in order to start the video - We put this in second slider because we initialize the slider with second slide active
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            },
        });
        yt['player3'] = new YT.Player('player3', {
            width: w,
            height: h,
            videoId: 'Fx-zmUwV1pc',
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
        event.target.playVideo();
        pd_initSwiperInfiniteNavigation();
    }

    swiper.on('transitionStart', function(){
        yt['player1'].pauseVideo();
        yt['player2'].pauseVideo();
        yt['player3'].pauseVideo();
    });

    swiper.on('transitionEnd', function(){
        var index = this.realIndex;
        var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide')[index];
        var slideVideo = slide.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        var slideVideoId = slideVideo.getAttribute('id');

        if(slideVideo != null || slideVideo != undefined){
            yt[slideVideoId].mute();
            yt[slideVideoId].playVideo();
        }
    });
    
    function pd_initSwiperInfiniteNavigation(){
        // Get elements.
        let elPrev = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');
        let elNext = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
        // Get total slides.
        let totalSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide').length;
        // Get current slide.
        let currentSlide = swiper.realIndex;
        // Get next slide.
        let nextSlide = currentSlide + 1;
        // Get previous slide.
        let prevSlide = currentSlide - 1;
        // Get last slide.
        let lastSlide = totalSlides - 1;
        // Get first slide.
        let firstSlide = 0;

        // Make infinite loop.
        elPrev.addEventListener('click', function(){
            // If current slide is first slide.
            if(currentSlide == firstSlide){
                // Go to last slide.
                swiper.slideTo(lastSlide);
            }else{
                // Go to previous slide.
                swiper.slideTo(prevSlide);
            }

            // Update current slide.
            currentSlide = swiper.realIndex;
            // Update next slide.
            nextSlide = currentSlide + 1;
            // Update previous slide.
            prevSlide = currentSlide - 1;
        });
        elNext.addEventListener('click', function(){
            // If current slide is last slide.
            if(currentSlide == lastSlide){
                // Go to first slide.
                swiper.slideTo(firstSlide);
            }else{
                // Go to next slide.
                swiper.slideTo(nextSlide);
            }

            // Update current slide.
            currentSlide = swiper.realIndex;
            // Update next slide.
            nextSlide = currentSlide + 1;
            // Update previous slide.
            prevSlide = currentSlide - 1;
        });
    }
```

```css
  .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide,
    .pd-swiperjs-video-iframe {
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 600px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-button-prev,
    .swiper-button-next {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        opacity: 1 !important;
        cursor: pointer !important;
        pointer-events: all !important;
    }

    .swiper-button-next:after, .swiper-button-prev:after {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #000;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .swiper-slide, .pd-swiperjs-video-iframe {
            height: 98%;
        }
        
        .swiper-button-prev,
        .swiper-button-next {
            display: none;
        }

        .pd-swiperjs-container-mobile {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .pd-swiperjs-row-mobile {
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- START SWIPERJS SLIDER -->
<div class="container pd-swiperjs-container-mobile">
    <div class="row pd-swiperjs-row-mobile">
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div id="player1" class="pd-swiperjs-video-iframe"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div id="player2" class="pd-swiperjs-video-iframe"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div id="player3" class="pd-swiperjs-video-iframe"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END SWIPERJS SLIDER -->
```